# Compute sequential max value in Pandas using vectorized operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
value
 10
 20
 30
 20
 40
 35
 60
 100
 50
 45
 135
```

and I want to compute a column with the max value until the respective row. The final dataframe should look like this:

```
value   max_value
 10        10
 20        20
 30        30
 20        30
 40        40
 35        40
 60        60
 100       100
 50        100
 45        100
 135       135
```

I can achieve this with this `iterrows` loop:

```
max_value = df['value'].iloc[0]
for index, row_data in df.iterrows():
    if row_data['value'] > max_value:
        max_value = row_data['value']
    df.at[index, 'max_value'] = max_value
```

but I'm looking for an efficient way of computing this using just vectorized operations, ideally without having to compute the max for all the previous rows again, since `max_value` will either be the previous `max_value` or the `value` of the respective row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.cummax()`

```py
df['max_value'] = df['value'].cummax()
```

```
print(df)

    value  max_value
0      10         10
1      20         20
2      30         30
3      20         30
4      40         40
5      35         40
6      60         60
7     100        100
8      50        100
9      45        100
10    135        135
```